Keep quotes in glue yaml R
I would like to keep the glue values as string when assigning to my yaml. Unfortunately, the quotes are not there. Here is some reproducible code:
library(yaml)
library(glue)
begin <- 1970
end <- 2020

yaml <- list(year = glue('between {begin} and {end}'))
yaml_text <- as.yaml(yaml)

cat(as.character(yaml_text), sep = "\n", file = "test.yaml", append = TRUE)

Output yaml file:
year: between 1970 and 2020

As you can see there is no string. I would like to have it like this 'year: between 1970 and 2020'. If we add space to the glue it does return as a string but including the whitespace which is not what I want:
library(yaml)
library(glue)
begin <- 1970
end <- 2020

yaml <- list(year = glue(' between {begin} and {end}')) # white space added
yaml_text <- as.yaml(yaml)

cat(as.character(yaml_text), sep = "\n", file = "test.yaml", append = TRUE)

Output:
year: ' between 1970 and 2020'

As you can see it is now in quotes. I don't understand why. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to get quoted values in a yaml while using glue?

I think that, since indentation is important in YAML, it converts it to a string to preserve the white space in the beginning and not mixing it with an extra indentation. But I don't know how to force this behaviour without white spaces...

Possible duplicate.  glue::single_quote() and glue::double_quote() exist.
